# Angular Material 2 Form Field Appearance Problems

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to add the fill appearance to form inputs in my application. I have imported MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule and added appearance="fill" to my mat-form-field element but I am not seeing any fill. Am I missing a step here?

[Current Application Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4qZz.png)

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="/assets/img/bt_logo_blue.svg" class="bt-logo">
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log in</h2>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <input matInput type="text" class="input-block-level" id="input-email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <i class="fal fa-envelope" matSuffix></i>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <input matInput type="password" class="input-block-level" id="input-password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" color="primary">Log in</button><br/>
        <h6 id="forgot-password-link" routerLink="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</h6>
        <hr>
        <h6 id="no-account">Don't have an account? <a routerLink="/signup">Sign Up</a></h6>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please provide [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. Are you seeing any errors in your console with the form loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the wrong version of Material. What version are you on? Just 30 minutes ago the appearance attribute was edited in git. So things are changing fast over there.

Here is a working version using 6.0.1:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndbydqgqeqx

And another one on 5.2.4 that is not working:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydqbci

You can take a look at the material changelog to see all the form-field changes being made recently:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: This sounds viable - I Just made this StackBlitz using material version 6.0.1 and the OPs code works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxjsm1

Comment: Yep, I think you are correct. I only just now realized that you could toggle the Material version on their site and sure enough when it is set to  5.2.4 the appearance property goes away. I will have to upgrade Thanks!

Comment: @PeterGarcia no problem! Confirm my answer please?